# Postback does not display updated content

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

There is a comment page in my web app , when user adds a comment , a postback request is generated but when page in rendered again, recently added comment is not shown .Is there any way to display the updated comment list on the page after submitting a comment ?

```
<p:panel header="Comments :">
        <ui:repeat var="comment"
            value="#{ticketBean.getCommentList(ticketBean.ticketModel.ticketId)}">
            <p:panel header="#{comment.username} , #{comment.formattedDate}">
                <h:outputText id="coment" value="#{comment.remark}"></h:outputText>
            </p:panel>
            <p:separator />
        </ui:repeat>
    </p:panel>

    <h:form id="commentForm">
        <p:inputTextarea value="#{ticketBean.comment.remark}" />
        <h:inputHidden value="#{ticketBean.comment.username}"
            id="hiddenUserName" />
        <h:inputHidden value="#{ticketBean.ticketModel.ticketId}"
            id="hiddenTicketId" />
        <p:commandButton action="#{ticketBean.addComment}" value="Comment"></p:commandButton>
    </h:form>
```

i am returning the name of the same page from `ticketBean.addComment` , here is `TicketBean#addComment` ,

```
public String addComment() {
        comment.setTicketId(ticketModel.getTicketId());
        comment.setUsername("alok.dac");
        cDao.addComment(comment);
        return "viewDetailedTicket";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple ways to do that. You can add an `ajax="false"` attribute the `p:commandButton`. This will rerender the whole page.

Or you specify which components to update, either add an `update="@all"` to the `p:commandButton` or specify an `id` for your panel and update that.

Comment: thanks @Syren, but  what if i want to update multiple components on the page ? can it also be done using update  attribute in commnadButton?

Comment: Yes. E.g. you can do something like `update="componentInForm :componentInRootHirachy :someRootComponent:subComponent"`. Any number of components can be specified in this way. You can also check section "Search Expression Framework" in the Primefaces docs ( found [here](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_2.pdf) ) for PF-specific options.

Comment: and i have tried it with comma separated ids (ex. update="id1,id2,id3") , that is also working .